# Checking well-definedness of distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I'm struggling to prove the well-definedness of distribution.

Let $\vec{b} \in \mathcal{D}^\prime (\mathbb{R}^n)^n$. For $N>0$, define a smooth cutoff function $\psi_N (x)=\psi (x/N)$, where 
$$ \psi \in C^\infty_0 (\mathbb{R}^n),\quad \psi (x)=1\quad \text{if } |x|\leq \frac{1}{2},\quad \psi(x)=0 \quad \text{if } |x|>1.$$

Define $f_N =\Delta^{-1} \mathrm{div}(\psi_N \vec{b})$. Then I want to gurantee $f_N$ is well-defined in terms of distributions.

How can I show it?

Comment: I'm not sure this could be a proof. Passing inverse Laplacian to distributional part. Next, taking formal adjoint of divergence. Finally pass the cutoff function to right. Then the right hand side is in C^infty with compact support. Since b is a distribution, done.

Comment: I'm not sure the above way is right.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Also, since $f_N$ is a distribution, you don't mean to say 'pass inverse laplacian to distributional part'.

Comment: @Calvin Khor: The sentence means taking a pairing $<f_N , \varphi>=<\Delta^{-1} g, \varphi> =<g,\Delta^{-1}\varphi>$ (sorry for my poor english expression). I want to verify $f_N$ is a well-defined distribution.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say that you passed it to the side with $\phi$ which is a function

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks very much!

Comment: what is $\Delta^{-1}$ ? the convolutive inverse of the Laplacian (something like $f \mapsto f \ast \frac{1}{\|x\|^2}$ ?)

Comment: @user1952009 Yes. It is a convolution operator with fundamental solution of Laplacian.

Comment: I think that this problem follows from the identity $\Delta u = f$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$.

Comment: @JohnMartin Does we have a unique solvability when $f$ is a distribution with compact support? I'm not sure about this.

Comment: @Will Kwon I know the demonstration, by duality, that if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $u:=E_n \ast f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $E_n$ is fundamental solution of the Laplace equations, and it is a distributianal solution of Poisson equations, i.e. it's true that $\Delta u = f$ in the sense of the distributions. So I think from this result you can reason in terms of $\Delta^{-1}$. Then this fact it can extend the product space using the distributional divergence. This is just my idea.

Comment: @JohnMartin The approach you gave me is not familiar to me (due to my lack of study) I'll consider it deeply. Thank you for your comment.